# How do I find all elements that contain a specific comment?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file and I need to select all of the elements that contain a special comment.

```
<items>
  <item>
    <name>A</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <!--SPECIAL-->
    <name>B</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>C</name>
  </item>
</items>
```

I can load this XML into an `XMLDocument`

```
PS> $catalog = [xml](Get-Content .\items.xml)
```

And enumerate the items. I can see their names, but no comments!

```
PS> $catalog.items.item

name : A

name : B

name : C
```

I messed around with an `XmlTextReader` and `XmlReaderSettings` (which defaults `IgnoreComments` to `false`), but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Do you have the option to use Attributes instead of comments?

Comment: Nope, it's not my file. I would/could pre-process it if I could read comments, but then I'd probably have the solution anyway :)

Comment: How about using xpath `SelectNodes("//item[comment()='SPECIAL']")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$catalog.items.item.'#comment'
```